# Watch service acquiring file handle

Tags: java, watchservice

I am using java watch service in my application to get notified of any file changes.

But the problem is watch service holds the file handle of the parent directory.
For e.g. if my hierarchy is

```
F
-F1
 -F2
```

When i register watch service on F, F1 and F2. Then if i try to rename or delete the  parent folder F, there comes a message of file is opened by another program which is the watch service.

I have found this issue mentioned here http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do;jsessionid=76a42b61021a94ffffffffa049f7587fd4149?bug_id=6972833

Also have tried the File_Tree modifier to circumvent this issue but it did not help. Probably i have not used the File_Tree modifier properly.

Below is the sample code which i am testing on. Please check if the usage of FILE_TREE modifier is proper in my code.

```
/**
 * Example to watch a directory (or tree) for changes to files.
 * This code is direct copy from https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/examples/WatchDir.java
 */

public class FileWatcher {

    private final WatchService watcher;
    private final Map<WatchKey,Path> keys;
    private final boolean recursive;
    private boolean trace = false;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    static <T> WatchEvent<T> cast(WatchEvent<?> event) {
        return (WatchEvent<T>)event;
    }

    /**
     * Register the given directory with the WatchService
     */
    private void register(Path dir) throws IOException {
        WatchKey key = dir.register(watcher, new WatchEvent.Kind[] { ENTRY_CREATE, ENTRY_DELETE, ENTRY_MODIFY, OVERFLOW },com.sun.nio.file.ExtendedWatchEventModifier.FILE_TREE);
        if (trace) {
            Path prev = keys.get(key);
            if (prev == null) {
                System.out.format("register: %s\n", dir);
            } else {
                if (!dir.equals(prev)) {
                    System.out.format("update: %s -> %s\n", prev, dir);
                }
            }
        }
        keys.put(key, dir);
    }

    /**
     * Register the given directory, and all its sub-directories, with the
     * WatchService.
     */
    private void registerAll(final Path start) throws IOException {
        // register directory and sub-directories
        Files.walkFileTree(start, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
            @Override
            public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path dir, BasicFileAttributes attrs)
                    throws IOException
                    {
                register(dir);
                return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
                    }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Creates a WatchService and registers the given directory
     */
    FileWatcher(Path dir, boolean recursive) throws IOException {
        this.watcher = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();
        this.keys = new HashMap<WatchKey,Path>();
        this.recursive = recursive;

        if (recursive) {
            System.out.format("Scanning %s ...\n", dir);
            registerAll(dir);
            System.out.println("Done.");
        } else {
            register(dir);
        }

        // enable trace after initial registration
        this.trace = true;
    }

    /**
     * Process all events for keys queued to the watcher
     */
    void processEvents() {
        for (;;) {

            // wait for key to be signalled
            WatchKey key;
            try {
                key = watcher.take();
            } catch (InterruptedException x) {
                return;
            }

            Path dir = keys.get(key);
            if (dir == null) {
                System.err.println("WatchKey not recognized!!");
                continue;
            }

            for (WatchEvent<?> event: key.pollEvents()) {
                WatchEvent.Kind kind = event.kind();

                // TBD - provide example of how OVERFLOW event is handled
                if (kind == OVERFLOW) {
                    continue;
                }

                // Context for directory entry event is the file name of entry
                WatchEvent<Path> ev = cast(event);
                Path name = ev.context();
                Path child = dir.resolve(name);

                // print out event
                System.out.format("%s: %s\n", event.kind().name(), child);

                // if directory is created, and watching recursively, then
                // register it and its sub-directories
                if (recursive && kind == ENTRY_CREATE) {
                    try {
                        if (Files.isDirectory(child, NOFOLLOW_LINKS)) {
                            registerAll(child);
                        }
                    } catch (IOException x) {
                        // ignore to keep sample readbale
                    }
                }
            }

            // reset key and remove from set if directory no longer accessible
            boolean valid = key.reset();
            if (!valid) {
                keys.remove(key);

                // all directories are inaccessible
                if (keys.isEmpty()) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    static void usage() {
        System.err.println("usage: java WatchDir [-r] dir");
        System.exit(-1);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // parse arguments
        if (args.length == 0 || args.length > 2) {
            usage();
        }
        boolean recursive = false;
        int dirArg = 0;
        if (args[0].equals("-r")) {
            if (args.length < 2) {
                usage();
            }
            recursive = false;
            dirArg++;
        }

        // register directory and process its events
        Path dir = Paths.get(args[dirArg]);
        new FileWatcher(dir, recursive).processEvents();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dug a little bit into the docs and find out a fix for myself.

With the File_Tree modifier a single key is assigned to all the folders/dirs. So we need to work with a single key. 
Hence i am trying to reregister with the same root path and then reusing the key on every new creation of an item under the watched directory.

major take aways are

1. Recursive way of visting every folder in the directory is not required anymore.
2. Re registering on the same path is required whenever a new folder is created under the root path because only key is required every time
3. I am not sure on the performance part since everytime i am registering the whole path. probably i will do some performance analysis.

Below is the modified version of my code. Let me know if the code is not clear

```
package com.sap.mcm;  

import static java.nio.file.StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE;
import static java.nio.file.StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_DELETE;
import static java.nio.file.StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY;
import static java.nio.file.StandardWatchEventKinds.OVERFLOW;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.FileSystems;
import java.nio.file.FileVisitResult;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.SimpleFileVisitor;
import java.nio.file.WatchEvent;
import java.nio.file.WatchKey;
import java.nio.file.WatchService;
import java.nio.file.attribute.BasicFileAttributes;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import com.sun.nio.file.ExtendedWatchEventModifier;

/**
 * Example to watch a directory (or tree) for changes to files.
 * This code is direct copy from https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/examples/WatchDir.java
 */
public class FileWatcher {

    private final WatchService watcher;
    private final Map<WatchKey,Path> keys;
    private final boolean recursive;
    private boolean trace = true;
    private Path parentDir;
    private WatchKey key;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    static <T> WatchEvent<T> cast(WatchEvent<?> event) {
        return (WatchEvent<T>)event;
    }

    /**
     * Register the given directory with the WatchService
     */
    private void register(Path dir) throws IOException {
        try {
            parentDir = dir;
            key = parentDir.register(watcher, new WatchEvent.Kind[] { ENTRY_CREATE, ENTRY_DELETE, ENTRY_MODIFY, OVERFLOW }, ExtendedWatchEventModifier.FILE_TREE);
        } catch (UnsupportedOperationException usoe) {
            usoe.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void reregister() throws IOException {
        // WatchKey key = keys.get(path);
        key.cancel();
        register(parentDir);
    }
    /**
     * Register the given directory, and all its sub-directories, with the
     * WatchService.
     */
    private void registerAll(final Path start) throws IOException {
        // register directory and sub-directories
        Files.walkFileTree(start, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
            @Override
            public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path dir, BasicFileAttributes attrs)
                    throws IOException {
                register(dir);
                return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Creates a WatchService and registers the given directory
     */
    FileWatcher(Path dir, boolean recursive) throws IOException {
        this.watcher = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();
        this.keys = new HashMap<WatchKey,Path>();
        this.recursive = recursive;

        if (recursive) {
            System.out.format("Scanning %s ...\n", dir);
            registerAll(dir);
            System.out.println("Done.");
        } else {
            register(dir);
        }

        // enable trace after initial registration
        this.trace = true;
    }

    /**
     * Process all events for keys queued to the watcher
     */
    void processEvents() {
        for (;;) {

            // wait for key to be signalled
            WatchKey key;
            try {
                key = watcher.take();
            } catch (InterruptedException x) {
                return;
            }

            // Path dir = keys.get(key);
            // if (dir == null) {
            // System.err.println("WatchKey not recognized!!");
            // continue;
            // }
            if (this.key != key) {
                return;
            }
            for (WatchEvent<?> event: key.pollEvents()) {
                WatchEvent.Kind kind = event.kind();

                // TBD - provide example of how OVERFLOW event is handled
                if (kind == OVERFLOW) {
                    continue;
                }

                // Context for directory entry event is the file name of entry
                WatchEvent<Path> ev = cast(event);
                ev.context();

                // print out event
                System.out.format("%s: %s \n", event.kind().name(), event.context());

                // if directory is created, and watching recursively, then
                // register it and its sub-directories
                if (kind == ENTRY_CREATE) {
                    try {
                        // if (Files.isDirectory(child, NOFOLLOW_LINKS)) {
                        reregister();
                        // }
                    } catch (IOException x) {
                        // ignore to keep sample readbale
                    }
                }
            }

            // reset key and remove from set if directory no longer accessible
            boolean valid = this.key.reset();
            if (!valid) {
                keys.remove(key);

                // all directories are inaccessible
                if (keys.isEmpty()) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    static void usage() {
        System.err.println("usage: java WatchDir [-r] dir");
        System.exit(-1);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // parse arguments
        if (args.length == 0 || args.length > 2) {
            usage();
        }
        boolean recursive = false;
        int dirArg = 0;
        if (args[0].equals("-r")) {
            if (args.length < 2) {
                usage();
            }
            recursive = false;
            dirArg++;
        }

        // register directory and process its events
        Path dir = Paths.get(args[dirArg]);
        new FileWatcher(dir, recursive).processEvents();
    }
}
```